# How to set base image in Dockerfile based on an external (config) file?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I'd like to set the base image in my Dockerfile based on a configuration file.

Let's say my config file is called `config.json` and its content is:

```
{
  "repo" : "ubuntu",
  "tag"  : "latest"
}
```

I'd like my Dockerfile to look something like:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE_REPO=<parse repo from config.json>
ARG BASE_IMAGE_TAG=<parse tag from config.json>
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE_REPO}:${BASE_IMAGE_TAG}
...
```

But I know it can't be done that way.

** edit **
one of my requirements is that we can still build the docker image using the basic `docker build . -t foo:bar` command.

---

Is there an elegant way to achieve my goal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the docker file itself, there is no way of doing this.

An option you could try (for development) is docker-compose

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  development:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE_REPO: ubuntu
        BASE_IMAGE_TAG: latest
```

Or you could use a script to do this combined with docker build.
Something like this, if you use [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse the config.json file

```bash
docker build --build-arg BASE_IMAGE_REPO =$(jq .repo config.json) --build-arg BASE_IMAGE_TAG=$(jq .tag config.json) -t example .
```

On the other hand, you are setting defaults that can be overwritten during build anyway (see above). So I personally also don't see why you should not be using a hard-coded default.

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE_REPO=ubuntu
ARG BASE_IMAGE_TAG=latest
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE_REPO}:${BASE_IMAGE_TAG}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. However, I forgot to mention that one of my requirements is that we could still build the docker image with the basic command `docker build . -t foo:bar` ...

Comment: With that requirement, you can only use the defaults in the dockerfile.